# `pkg_resources.working_set` contains distributions whose name begins with character "-"

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pkg-resources

On my installation (Python 3.8.1 on Windows 7), if I run the following code:

```py
import pkg_resources
print([d.key for d in pkg_resources.working_set if d.key[0] == "-"])
```

I get the following output:

```py
['-fi', '-', '-.fi', '-ffi']
```

What are these packages beginning with "-"?

I add that on my system, every time I upgrade the package "cffi" with command `pip install --upgrade cffi`, I get the following error (which after some research online I guess is due to the antivirus, which I cannot disable):

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Accesso negato: 'C:\\Users\\myuser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-uninstall-pai0_5kc\\_cffi_backend.cp38-win_amd64.pyd'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

but anyway the upgrade is successful (I can confirm it with `pip show cffi`).

Could those packages resulting from this? Should I get rid of them and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could those packages resulting from this?

No. Error "Access denied" means you don't have enough privileges to write to a system directory.

Run `pip install` as Administrator. Better: run `pip install --user`. The best: use a virtual environment.

> Should I get rid of them

Not strictly necessary but you better get rid.

> how?

By removing their subdirectories from `site-packages` directory.